# Fetch data with default rows

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have tables `resource`, `item` and `price`:

```
item
+--------+---------+
| itemId | name    |
+--------+---------+
|   2743 | Product |
+--------+---------+

resource
+------------------+-----+----------------+--+
|resourceId | key | value          | groupId |
+-----------+-----+----------------+---------+
|        45 |   1 | Client         |       3 |
|        46 |   2 | Manufacturer   |       3 |
|        69 |   1 | Delivery       |       4 |
|        70 |   2 | Collection     |       4 |
|        71 |   3 | Assembly       |       4 |
|        72 |   4 | Client Request |       4 |
|        73 |   1 | Draft          |       5 |
|        74 |   2 | Not Confirmed  |       5 |
|        75 |   3 | Confirmed      |       5 |
+-----------+-----+----------------+---------+

price
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+
| priceId | serviceId | itemId | price    |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+
|     294 |         4 |      0 |  20.0000 |
|     293 |         3 |      0 |  20.0000 |
|     292 |         2 |      0 |  20.0000 |
|     291 |         1 |      0 |  20.0000 |
|     290 |         1 |   2743 |  18.4000 |
|     288 |         1 |   2738 |  10.0000 |
|     267 |         4 |   2721 |   0.0000 |
|     266 |         3 |   2721 |   0.0000 |
|     265 |         2 |   2721 |   0.0000 |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

Rows in table resource with groupId=4 are services. They are refered to via column `key` from table `price` (`serviceId`). As you can see I have default prices for those services (first four rows in `price` with `itemId`=0). I need to fetch as many `pirce` rows as there are services for a given item. If that item doesn't have a price for a service, service's default price should be fetched. For example, the item with id = 2743 has price for service Delivery. For all other services their default prices should be returned. What I need is a result like this:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+-----+----------------+---------+
| priceId | serviceId | itemId | price    |resourceId | key | value          | groupId |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+-----+----------------+---------+
|     290 |         1 |   2743 |  18.4000 |        69 |   1 | Delivery       |       4 |
|     292 |         2 |   NULL |  17.0000 |        70 |   2 | Collection     |       4 |
|     293 |         3 |   NULL |  13.0000 |        71 |   3 | Assembly       |       4 |
|     294 |         4 |   NULL |   9.0000 |        72 |   4 | Client Request |       4 |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+-----+----------------+---------+
```

Here is a query I tried. I get as many rows as services, but all of them have have the same price (that of the item)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `price` AS `p`
 INNER JOIN `item` ON p.id = item.id
 RIGHT JOIN `resource` AS `res` ON 1 = 1
 WHERE (res.groupId = 4)
   AND (p.itemId = 2743);
```

Comment: Please show us the query you already tried - I hope you tried it yourself already.

Comment: See LEFT JOIN and COALESCE() - although it's ridiculous to provide an incomplete data set.

Comment: I fear I'm confused by your schema. Please [edit] your question. It looks like `resource.key` values are usable for joining to `price.serviceId`. Is that correct? I think your specification says rows with `price.itemId` values of zero due for special handling, because they show fallback prices for rows in your `resource` table with `resource.groupId`=4. Is that correct? `RIGHT JOIN` is a little strange, and `RIGHT JOIN ... ON 1=1` is really bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.itemId, coalesce(p1.price, p0.price)
from item i
cross join price p0
left  join price p1 
  on  p1.serviceId = p0.serviceId
  and p1.itemId    = i.itemId
where i.itemId  = 2743
  and p0.itemId = 0
```